# Remove everything after tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am extracting plaintext from HTML emails using BeautifulSoup. I've got everything working nicely except for one issue. My emails often have replies included below the message at the top. So I have threaded emails, and I end up capturing the same text repeatedly. In most cases, I want to just get rid of everything after the first `<div>` tag I find. If I print, `soup.contents`, it outputs the following:

`p
None
p
None
p
None
p
None
p
None
p
None
p
None
p
None
p
None
p
None
p
None
div
None
meta
None
style
None
div
None
p`

I am looking to return a BeautifulSoup object with everything passed the first div tag removed.

HTMLwise, here's the before and after I'm going for:
**Before:**

```
<p> Hi Joe </p>
<p> I will be at the meeting tonight</p>
<p> Allison </p>

<div style='border-width: 1pt medium medium; border-style: solid none none; border-color: rgb(181, 196, 223) currentColor currentColor; font-family: "Arial","sans-serif";'>
<p style="margin: 2px 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<b>From: </b>John Doe &lt;jdoe@example.com&gt;</p>
<p style="margin: 2px 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<b>Sent: </b>Wednesday, May 30, 2018 6:48 AM</p>
<p style="margin: 2px 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<b>To: </b>Allison &lt;allison@example.com&gt;</p>
<p style="margin: 2px 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<b>Subject: </b>RE: meeting tonight</p>
<p style="margin: 2px 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                 </p>
</div>

<p>Will you be at the meeting tonight?</p>
```

**After:**

```
<p> Hi Joe </p>
<p> I will be at the meeting tonight</p>
<p> Allison </p>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add input HTML and desired output HTML?

Comment: Sure..thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3):

In BeautifulSoup4, you can use the find_all_next method to delete everything after the tag, including the tag itself. This is only going to work if the elements afterwards are defined, e.g. they can't just belong to the Body element.

```
target = soup.find('div')
for e in target.find_all_next():
    e.clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way in this case is just run `re` and remove all contents after first `<div>` tag:

```
s = """<p> Hi Joe </p>
<p> I will be at the meeting tonight</p>
<p> Allison </p>

<div style='border-width: 1pt medium medium; border-style: solid none none; border-color: rgb(181, 196, 223) currentColor currentColor; font-family: "Arial","sans-serif";'>
<p style="margin: 2px 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<b>From: </b>John Doe &lt;jdoe@example.com&gt;</p>
<p style="margin: 2px 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<b>Sent: </b>Wednesday, May 30, 2018 6:48 AM</p>
<p style="margin: 2px 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<b>To: </b>Allison &lt;allison@example.com&gt;</p>
<p style="margin: 2px 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<b>Subject: </b>RE: meeting tonight</p>
<p style="margin: 2px 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                 </p>
</div>

<p>Will you be at the meeting tonight?</p>"""

import re

new_s = re.sub(r'<div.*', '', s, flags=re.DOTALL).strip()
print(new_s)
```

Prints:

```
<p> Hi Joe </p>
<p> I will be at the meeting tonight</p>
<p> Allison </p>
```

Then you can feed this new string to BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(re.sub(new_s, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())
```

Outputs:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   Hi Joe
  </p>
  <p>
   I will be at the meeting tonight
  </p>
  <p>
   Allison
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I agree with this, but it isn't returning a BeautifulSoup object, or using BeautifulSoup whatsoever for that matter. If you put the result of your regular expression into BeautifulSoup as follows, it will return a BeautifulSoup object. soup = BeautifulSoup(new_s, 'html.parser')

Then return soup.

Comment: @CaitLANJenner Updated answer

Comment: Thanks to you both. I will try the method CaitLAN describes.

Comment: Excellent. I agree with this approach. BeautifulSoup is a HTML parser and being that the original code of interest was not even within a div tag, the string should be manipulated outside of BeautifulSoup. If the OP wants a soup object returned, this will still do so. I just hope that the OP had good reasons for using BeautifulSoup outside of removing the div, or obvious other solutions exist.

Comment: CaitLAN: My reason for using BeautifulSoup is to ultimately convert nasty HTML .eml files to plain text .txt files. Is there a better way without BeautifulSoup?